# SQL select and join values for all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, rows

Imagine that we have Tbl_Names and Tbl_General_Settings tables like that

**Tbl_User**

```
id   name    surname
1    Ahmet   ABC
2    Ali     XYZ
3    Selim   KLM
```

**Tbl_Global_Settings**

```
id   Setting1    Setting2    Setting3    Setting 4
1    on          off         yes         no
```

I need a SELECT query that shows those one row global settings for all rows in the tbl_user:

**Query result should be like this:**

```
id   name    surname   Setting1    Setting2    Setting3    Setting 4
1    Ahmet   ABC       on          off         yes         no
2    Ali     XYZ       on          off         yes         no
3    Selim   KLM       on          off         yes         no
```

How can i do that? thanks..

Comment: You want a [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)?

Comment: Select that setting and save it to variable and when you selecting users, add that variable to everyone

Comment: It`s called cross join.

Comment: Ok thanks so much.. Found the solution: SELECT * FROM Tbl_User, Tbl_Global_Settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution: **SELECT * FROM Tbl_User, Tbl_Global_Settings**

Answer (score 6):

In your sample, you try to perform a cartesian product.

This operation can be performed in MySql (and other DBMS) with CROSS JOIN, as follow:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl_User u
CROSS JOIN Tbl_Global_Settings gs
```

CROSS JOIN (Cartesian product) take each row of the first table and create a link with every row of the second table. In your example you have 3 rows as result because 3 (users) x 1 (global settings) = 3.

If you have 2 global setting the result will be 6. (3 x 2)